# Pass trigger values to APEX class

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to pass field values from trigger to an APEX class.

I have created the trigger but I don't know how to call the class from trigger and how to receive these values in the class.

```
trigger trgTestCustomer on TestCustomer__c (after insert) {

for(TestCustomer__c t: Trigger.new){

         string newName;
         newName = t.Name;
     } 

}
```

Any snippet will be helpful. Can a List object of all the values be passed to class?

Answer (score 3):

The context variables `Trigger.new` and `Trigger.old` are typed as `List<sobject>`, where `sobject` is the object your trigger fires on. `Trigger.newMap` and `Trigger.oldMap` are typed as `Map<Id, sobject>`.

All of these values can be passed to a class like any other parameters, and it's very common to do so as part of a quality trigger framework. For example:

```
TestCustomerTriggerHandler.afterInsert(Trigger.new);
```

I recommend reviewing [Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) and  [Trigger Context Variables Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm) from the Apex Developer Guide.

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger trgTestCustomer on TestCustomer__c (after insert) {
   TriggerHandler.method1(Trigger.new)
    for(TestCustomer__c t: Trigger.new){
     string newName;
     newName = t.Name;
 } 
}
public class TriggerHandler{
    public static void method1(List<TestCustomer__c> lstCustomers){
       //your code comes here
    }
}`
```

Hope this should help on how to pass context variables from trigger to apex class